# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: Expected a string or a class/function

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have an expo application that is supposed to function like a 'Camera'. I've tried many solutions but they did not seem to work.

> The error is : "Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid expected
>   a string (for build-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   elements) but got object. Check the render method of "CameraPage".

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import CameraPage from './src/camera.page';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <CameraPage />
        );
    };
};
```

camera.page.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import * as Camera from 'expo-camera';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions'

import styles from './styles';

export default class CameraPage extends React.Component {
    camera = null;

    state = {
        hasCameraPermission: null,
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const camera = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
        const audio = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.AUDIO_RECORDING);
        const hasCameraPermission = (camera.status === 'granted' && audio.status === 'granted');

        this.setState({ hasCameraPermission });
    };

    render() {
        const { hasCameraPermission } = this.state;

        if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
            return <View />;
        } else if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
            return <Text>Access to camera has been denied.</Text>;
        }

        return (
            <View>
                <Camera
                    style={styles.preview}
                    ref={camera => this.camera = camera}
                />
            </View>
        );
    };
};
```

Comment: Please improve hasPermission property
for example
const hasCameraPermission = (camera.status === 'granted' && audio.status === 'granted' ? 'hasPermission' : 'noPermission');
Assign right value to property

Comment: can you post expo snack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You import the `Camera` component in the wrong way. The correct one is:

```
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
```

Please, check the documentation [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/) and see the [working demo](https://snack.expo.io/@hristoeftimov/5ada88)

Comment: Ah my mistake. Thank you

Comment: If my answer was helpful for you, you can accept it or upvote it. Please, appreciate the work of contributors :)